# A weakly open subset of the unit ball of the Read's space $R$ (an infinite-dimensional Banach space) is unbounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology, weak-lp-spaces

We know every weakly open subset of an infinite-dimensional Banach vector space X is unbounded.

Now, Read's space $R$ (an infinite-dimensional Banach space) has the property:
there is $ρ >0$ such that every weakly open subset of the unit ball of $R$ has the diameter greater than or equal to $ρ$.

My question is: since every weakly open subset of an infinite-dimensional Banach vector space X is unbounded then how can a weakly open subset of $R$ be inside the unit ball of $R$?

Comment: I think it means subspace topology.